# How do I make a library available to the entire application in Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have a number of methods that I would like to make available to the entire application. Based on what I read and researched, I did the following:

```
1. Created a lib/app_lib.rb
```

and defined some methods in it.

```
2. In config/application.rb, I added the following lines:

    config.assets.enabled = true
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

This however is not working, as when I try to call one of the methods in any of the controllers or views, I get the error message:

```
undefined local variable or method ....
```

This is for Rails 4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case `lib/app_lib.rb` is a module, you need to include it into your application controller!

Comment: As in add the following to application_controller.rb:  require 'lib/app_lib.rb'?

Comment: Yes, this solved the problem although I thought that autoloading would take care of it as well

Comment: no, not as in `require ...` more as in `include ....`. rails will require the file for you as long as it follows rails naming conventions, which means the content of app_lib.rb is class AppLib or module AppLib